# Identification from implicit function

Tags: econometrics, identifiability

Suppose my observed data $y$ and $x$ is generated by the following relationship for each observation $i$:

$$ y_i = h(y_i,\theta) + x_i + \varepsilon_i$$

where $x_i$ is a strictly exogenous variable , $\varepsilon_i$ is an i.i.d. error term and $\theta$ the vector or parameters of interest. Assume that the solution to this equation is unique.

When $h$ is sufficiently simple (e.g. linear), I can manually solve for $y_i$ and consistently estimate $\theta$ with OLS.

However, when $h$ is more involved, e.g., $h(y_i, \theta) = (1+\exp(\theta_1 - \theta_2 y_i)) / \theta_2$, then there is no closed-form solution. It feels tempting to estimate $\theta$ using non-linear least squares:
$$ \arg \min_\theta \sum_i(y_i - h(y_i, \theta) - x_i)^2$$

but there are obvious endogeneity concerns with respect to the right-hand side of this expression.

Is there any instrument that allows dealing with these endogeneity concerns? Or how else is such a non-linear relationship without closed-form solution approached?

Comment: $y_i$ is generated by a function of $y_i$ itself? Are you sure that this is correct? $h(y_i, \theta) = y_i - x_i - \varepsilon_i $.

Comment: Why not write the relation as $x_i=f(y_i,\theta)+\epsilon_i$ where $\epsilon_i=-\varepsilon_i$ and $f(y_i,\theta)=y_i-h(y_i,\theta)$? That's a standard regression setting, presenting no special problems.

Comment: How is that supposed to help when $x$ is assumed exogenous but $y_i$ is assumed endogenous (if that is indeed what @bonifaz means by "obvious endogeneity concerns")

Comment: @Stop "Endogenous" and "exogenous" do not add anything to the model.  If they do, then that needs to be incorporated in the model statement!

Comment: @Tim, yes, that's what I meant with 'implicitly defined'.

Comment: @whuber I struggle to make sense of that comment. Is it because rather than using the words "endogenous"/"exogenous" which you perhaps see as to vague you would prefer a more precise mathematical statement? Or does it reflect some other disagreement with respect to approaching the question?

Comment: @Stop This question begins with the precise mathematical statement of the model.  Except insofar as additional text might explain the symbols, that overrides all else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is some rough code in R implementing the non-linear two stage least squares estimator under the assumption that $\mathbb E[\epsilon\lvert x] = 0$. Just to see if it works ... it seems to be working up to the point of standard over-underflow issues there might be. But the non-linear two stage least squares estimator should be implemented in most statistical software.

```
N <- 10000
x <- rnorm(N)
e <- rnorm(N)
x <- c(0,x)
e <- c(0,e)
theta_1 <- 1
theta_2 <- 0.5

# function to solve for y for simulation of data given x and error e
makefunction <- function(x,e)
    {
        g <- function(y)
         {
         out <- y - (1 + exp(theta_1 - theta_2*y)/theta_2) - x - e
           return(out)
         }
      return(g)
    }

y <- rep(NA,N+1)
for (i in 1:(N+1))
    {
        g <- makefunction(x[i],e[i])
        y[i] <- uniroot(g,lower=-100,upper=100)$root 
    }

# y is endogenous ... non-zero covariance
cov(y,e)
# x is exogenous
cov(x,e)

# The error-function
r <- function(theta_1,theta_2)
    {
        out <- y - (1 + exp(theta_1 - theta_2*y)/theta_2) - x 
        return(out)
    }

# Instruments are function of x
X <- cbind(x,x^2,x^3) 
objective <- function(theta)
    {
        a1 <- theta[1]
        a2 <- theta[2]
        out <- rbind(r(a1,a2))%*%X%*%solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%cbind(r(a1,a2))
        return(out)
    }

optim(c(2,3),objective)
```

based on Amemiya (1983) in *the Handbook of Econometrics* formula (5.10).

I divide with $\theta_2$ within a prentheses instead of outside, but the code still illustrates how the estimator works so I'm not gonna alter it.

The residual function is

$$r(y,x,\theta) = y -h(y,\theta) - x$$

and

$$\mathbb E[r(y,x,\theta)\lvert x]=0$$ implying that

$$\mathbb E[t(x)r(y,x,\theta)]=0$$

for any function $t(x)$. Basically the two stage non linear least squares estimator is as such a general method of moments estimator.

A more recent text is Wooldridge, J.M. (1996) "Estimating systems of equations with different instruments for different equations" in *Journal of Econometrics*  an article the gist of which is recapitulated in his (2010) *Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data* in the chapter on GMM estimation page 530 - ...

Answer (score 2):

---

> *Or how else is such a non-linear relationship without closed-form
>   solution approached?*

For maximum likelihood we want the density of $y$ conditional on $x$ (because this is our sample), $f_{y|x}(y|x)$.

We start with making an assumption on the density of $\varepsilon$ conditional on $x$, $f_{\varepsilon|x}(\varepsilon|x)$.

When the relation is not implicit, say $y = ax + \varepsilon$ the change-of-variables method has a Jacobian determinant equal to unity so we simply have

$$f_{y|x}(y|x) = f_{\varepsilon|x}(y-ax|x)$$

and we can proceed as usual.
But when the relation is implicit we have

$$\varepsilon = y-h(y,\theta)-x \implies \frac{\partial \varepsilon}{\partial y} = 1- \frac{\partial h(y,\theta)}{\partial y}$$

so here, the observation density will be

$$f_{y|x}(y|x) = \left|1- \frac{\partial h(y,\theta)}{\partial y}\right| \cdot f_{\varepsilon|x}(y-h(y,\theta)-x|x)$$